# I only want data that is older than 28 days

Tags: datediff

Im looking to ignore all the data from the last 30 days.
this is what i have so far. Not sure if its a datedif or something else.

```
SELECT MOT_BOOKINGS_FW.REASON_CODE_FW,MOT_BOOKINGS_FW.VEHICLE_ID_FW,MOT_BOOKINGS_FW.BOOKING_STATUS_FW,MOT_BOOKINGS_FW.BOOKING_DATE_FW,MOT_BOOKINGS_FW.RECORD_NUMBER_FW FROM MOT_BOOKINGS_FW WHERE ((%CRS:%MOT_BOOKINGS_FW.REASON_CODE_FW = N'mot'%CRE:%) AND MOT_BOOKINGS_FW.ARCHIVE_STATUS_FW = N'N') 
ORDER BY MOT_BOOKINGS_FW.BOOKING_DATE_FW ASC
```

Comment: what's your RDBMS?

Comment: Not sure, think its oracle.

Answer (score 0):

By your sample code, it seems you're using Sql Server (but please, place your RDBMS as a tag).
What you need is something like this:

```
select * from table
where datediff(day,getdate(), date_column) > 28
```